# WPF: Same line drawn different?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a canvas and in it I'm drawing some lines:

```
for (int i = 1; i >= 100; i++)  
{  
  // Line  
  LineGeometry line = new LineGeometry();  
  line.StartPoint = new Point(i * 100, 0);  
  line.EndPoint = new Point(i * 100, 100 * 100);  

  // Path
  Path myPath = new Path();
  myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
  myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;

  // Add to canvas
  myPath.Data = line;
  canvas1.Children.Add(myPath);
}
```

Well, nothing special, but it makes problems - the lines are drawn different! The canvas is inside a scrollviewer, the following image shows different positions of the canvas, however the lines *should* look the same? Hell, how is this possible? The code above is the only code I've written by hand and it's the only content in the canvas. Anyone knows why this happens and how to prevent this? Thank you very much!
Screenshot: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/c01nrd6i/lines.png

**Update**

So maurizios solution works fine, but only as long as you use the LineGeometry to position the line, I still get blurry lines when I use the canvas to position the line.
Anyone can please help me with this? Thank you very much!

Sample screenshot and the code for it:

Screenshot: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/lu7z3mcv/canvasposprob.png

Code:

```
// LINE POSITIONED BY CANVAS -> LINE GETS BLURRY

// Line
LineGeometry line = new LineGeometry();
line.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
line.EndPoint = new Point(0, 100); 

// Path
Path myPath = new Path();
myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myPath.StrokeThickness = 5;
myPath.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
line.Freeze();

// Add to canvas
myPath.Data = line;
Canvas.SetLeft(myPath, 10); // LINE POSITIONED BY CANVAS:  x=10
Canvas.SetTop(myPath, 0);  // LINE POSITIONED BY CANVAS 
canvas1.SnapsToDevicePixels = true; // doesnt help
canvas1.Children.Add(myPath);

// LINE POSITIONED BY LINE GEOMETRY
// Line
LineGeometry line2 = new LineGeometry();
line2.StartPoint = new Point(20, 0);  //LINE POSITIONED BY LINE GEOMETRY: x=20
line2.EndPoint = new Point(20, 100); 

// Path
Path myPath2 = new Path();
myPath2.Stroke = Brushes.Blue;
myPath2.StrokeThickness = 5;
myPath2.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;
line2.Freeze();

// Add to canvas
myPath2.Data = line2;

// Don't use the canvas for positioning
//Canvas.SetTop(myPath, 10); //NEW
//Canvas.SetLeft(myPath, 10); //NEW
canvas1.Children.Add(myPath2);
```

Comment: How come this code gets executed at all? *i* is never larger or equals to 100.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the simple code you have explained here (Canvas in a Scrollviewer).  I suspect there is something else going on that is causing your issue... can you expand on your example?

Comment: @stefan: Updates to your question should be made by editing your question. I've removed your updates from below (only answers to your question should be there) and placed them within your question under the "Update" text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the Path property SnapsToDevicePixels to true.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I had some problems with the formatting, typed something new and at the end the condition (just in the post) was wrong, sorry. There is really no more code, the problem could be fixed using myPath.SnapsToDevicePixels = true;  
Thanks anyways for any attempt to help!

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see the answer, a little bit confusing that there are comments and answers.

Comment: If my proposed solution match with yours, I will be glad if you accept it. :-)